# new user does not recognize command `code`

Tags: ubuntu, bash, visual-studio

I have Windows Terminal running bash in Ubuntu and had been working under root by default.  I had isntalled the Remote wsl extension and successfuly opened vs code with `code .` on several occasions.  After realizing I should be working under a new_user with root access and sudo privelages but cannot launch vs code whic is installed on my windows c drive.  When I run `code` under new_user, I just get "Command 'code' not found, did you mean: ..."

I can't figure out if its a setting in a `.bashrc` or something under `/.vscode-server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to figure out the $PATH of the first user

```
which code
echo $PATH
```

switch to the second user and

```
PATH=$PATH:/PATHTOCODE;export PATH
```

and see if that works.